# How to write the select and case statement together in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to scala, I have a below sql that needs to be converted to scala, I have pasted what I tried but I am getting an error.

SQL code:

```
select (jess,
mark,
timestamp1,
timestamp2,
(CASE WHEN timestamp1>timstamp2 then null else salary) as salary,
(CASE WHEN timestamp1>timstamp2 then null else manager) as manager
)
```

Scala code I tried:

```
df.select (jess,
mark,
timestamp1,
timestamp2,
salary
)
.withColumn("salary", when($"timestamp1">$"timstamp2", salary ).otherwise("null"))
```

Is there a different way to write this.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The Scala script for node [ ScalaNode ] is invalid. Reason: [ could not interpret Scala script ].

Comment: How are you running your code? Is that the whole code? You'll need to give us more details on what you are doing.

Comment: I am running the code in spark 3.0

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above in comments, it will be easier with error message but what i can see for now:

1. You have missing comma in your select after "mark" column
2. In your example you are first doing select without "salary" column but then you are trying to use this column in when/otherwise. Include salary in first select or do the withColumn before selecting

Edit: If you want to have case/when inside select you can do it this way:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{when, col}


df.select(col("jess"),
col("mark"),
col("timestamp1"),
col("timestamp2"),
when(col("timestamp1") > col("timestamp2"),salary)
      .otherwise("null").alias("salary")
)
```

If you want to find out more about case/when please read this: https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-case-when-otherwise-example/

Comment: Please update your answer and show solution source code that the OP can refer.

Comment: I added the salary column in select now, I just want to know how to use case in the select statement in scala.

Comment: i added sample code for case/when inside select if you dont want to use separate withColumn before selecting.

Comment: I am getting an error telling cannot resolve, "null" and "salary" due to data type mismatch. Salary is string for now

Comment: For me its hard to say whats wrong, if salary is string then it should be alright as "null" is ofc also string. Please add more info about your df (schema) and paste what exactly are you running and what error is printed